# Increment/Decrement a value with JSP/Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm new with servlets. And my first try was to write a simple JSP-Application. Which increments are value starting with 0, and also possible to drecrement it.

Problems:

- the counter get no initalized with 0 (field is empty on the jsp page)
- when I click on the button "Increment it" it gets increment to 1, when I click   again on the same button, the value stays 1, but it should be 2 (on second click)

  ```
    @WebServlet("/countServlet")
      public class CounterServlet extends HttpServlet
      {
          private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
              HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
      {

          Counter counter;

          counter = (Counter) request.getAttribute("counter");
          if (counter == null)
          {
              counter = new Counter();
          }

          String increment = request.getParameter("increment");
          if (increment != null)
          {
              counter.increment();
          }

          String reset = request.getParameter("decrement");
          if (reset != null)
          {
              counter.decrement();
          }

          request.setAttribute("counter", counter.getCounter());
          request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);

      }
  ```

Counter model:

```
public class Counter {

    private int counter = 0;

    public void increment() {
        counter++;
    }

    public void decrement() {
        counter--;
    }

    public void reset() {
        counter = 0;
    }

    public int getCounter() {

        return counter;
    }
}
```

JSP:

```
<title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>

The current state of the counter:  ${counter}

<form action="countServlet" method="GET">
<input type="submit" name="increment" value="Increment it">
<input type="submit" name="decrement" value="Decrement it">
<input type="hidden" name="counter" value="${counter}">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is to do with the way you are getting your `Counter` instance

```
counter = (Counter) request.getAttribute("counter");
if (counter == null)
{
    counter = new Counter();
}
```

Your counter will always be `null` at this point because you are getting it from the `request` object which is a new instance for each incoming request. Attributes set on the request are not persisted between requests.

What you want to do is get it and store it on the session.

```
counter = (Counter) request.getSession().getAttribute("counter");
if (counter == null)
{
    counter = new Counter();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("counter", counter);
}
```

You should make any object that you are storing on the session `Serializable`

```
public class Counter implements java.io.Serializable {
```

**EDIT:**

As @daiscog correctly points out the

```
<input type="hidden" name="counter" value="${counter}">
```

in your JSP in not need as you will be storing the counter value in the session.

Comment: Thanks, it counts/decrements proper now. Do you have also an idea, why the value is not initalized with 0? Currently it counts from empty field to 1. :)

Comment: It might be worth adding that the hidden "counter" field in the HTML isn't required and isn't doing what the OP probably thinks it is.

Comment: @Matej when you say "empty field" can you elborate? In your `Counter` class the counter field is initalised to `0`.

Comment: I mean on the jsp page, before u pressed any button it shows: The current state of the counter:     , but it should be: The current state of the counter: 0